# AWS Windows Drive Letter Device Mapping and Naming

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, mapping, drive, drive-letters

[How to change assigned letter for Ephemeral drives automatically?](https://serverfault.com/questions/581074/how-to-change-assigned-letter-for-ephemeral-drives-automatically)

Answers part of my question. I'm not sure how to, after assigning a drive letter in ec2config, to then rename the drive. Not re-letter, that was already done via the drive mapping tool. I then would like to rename the drive.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to change the volume label? If so, you do that on the General tab of the properties pages of the disk, just like on any other Windows system.

Comment: Yes, the label. However, I'd like that to happen at boot after the drive letter assignment done via the above link using ec2config.